# Log and Toast doesn't fire on new activity

Tags: android

I have put in a Log.d on one of my buttons in a new activity however when I press that button the log.d does not fire. Also all the other Log.d code in the MainActivity fires.

```
public void accept(View view){
    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUser);
    info[1] = username.getText().toString();
    Log.d("info[1]:", info[1]);
    if(!info[1].isEmpty() || info[1] != null || info[1] == ""){

        MainActivity.imagePrev = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.igauto.PREVIEW", "accept");
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter username before", duration).show();
    }
}
```

here is the button on the new activity I create, When pressed it goes back to the main activity and finishes

Comment: Are you sure? what your logcat said then?

Comment: you should show where you called your accept method

Comment: Where is accept() being called from? Are you sure it's being fired at all?

Comment: @billynomates yes its being fired I assume because it takes me back to the main activity and does all the other operations correctly.

Comment: @Arash The accept method is attached to a button so on press it should fire

Comment: put a `log.d` before call accept method and also on the beginning of accept method.does it fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You have just understand this wrong:

```
   Log.d("info[1]:", info[1]);
```

Set a filter to eclipse logcat with a keyword for example "TEST", then do this log:

```
    Log.d("TEST","info[1]:"+info[1]);
```

And by the way, don´t compare Strings with == to another String like this

```
   if(!info[1].isEmpty() || info[1] != null || info[1] == "")
```

instead:

```
   if(!info[1].isEmpty() || info[1] != null || info[1].equals(""))
```